# javascript not pulling through - sticky bar

Tags: javascript, fixed, sticky

I'm using this: 
http://codesandnotes.com/sticky-elements/ (see the jsfiddle)
but I'm having problems in getting it to work. The pink css pulls through but it doesn't stick/doesn't change to red.

I've changed the article to an aside in the html and js. I'm using wordpress. I've added the js to the js folder and called it in the header which is pulling into the correct template. I've added the css to the main style.css. The js and css files are in different locations- could this be what's stopping the js being called?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It would be useful to include a minimal working example in the question itself, as well as linking elsewhere.

Comment: Almost 100% chance of your wordpress theme be the one messing up with your CSS. Try inspecting the element and it's parent and remove all unnecessary `display`, `float` and `position` rules

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the comment. The jsfiddle I've referenced above takes you to a working example. I've been asked not to post an actual link as it's to a client's website, I know it would be handy, sorry about that.

Comment: Can you post the wordpress theme and what part of it you are trying to stick?

Answer (score 0):

is it fixed?

Anyway!

First add `css` and `jQuery` Library link to your `WordPress Header`. Then add `html codes` from the jsfiddle. after all the things done.

include `copied js script` file from the jsfiddle to the bottom of the page. See below `code` will help you to understand. *but it's in html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    <link href="copied_css_file_from_the_jsfiddle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script><!-- jQuery Library -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script><!-- jQuery Library -->
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is the proper way <small>How to use css js and html in correct way</small></p>

    <!-- add the html code from the JSFIDDLE-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            //Copy and paste the script from the JSFIDDLE
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Contact me by searching `yeshansachithak` in any social network. Thanks